# How to find all results that contain x in any property in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to be able to find all the pictures that contain a certain parameter, no matter which property contains that parameter, for example:

Say I type "John Snow" on the search bar, I'd like the result to be all pictures posted by John Snow (a person with that name), all pictures *of* John Snow (the character) and any picture containing that string in the description.

Is it possible to do this in the mongoose framework with node and express or is the answer to find by all possible properties and then remove duplicates?

```
var picSchema = new mongo.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    description: String,
    comments: [{
        type: mongo.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
    }],
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongo.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    }
});
```

Comment: I know it is not an answer for your question but why you do not want to specify exact fields names for such a query? From the optimization stand point you could add indexes or tweak your MongoDB to optimize such a search for the future queries.

Comment: I want to make a generic or broad search, how could I tweak the schema to optimize this kind of search? I thought about adding "tags" and populate it with the author, name and everything when it's created (and also allowing for other tags to be added).

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you could create and index:

```
picSchema.index({name: 'text', description: 'text', image: 'text'});
```

After node restart you would be able to perform search in the next way:

```
pic.find({ $text : { $search : "keyword" } }).exec((err, response)=> {});
```

Don't forget to register a model with your schema